# How to print the content of my combobox to a listview? Visual Studio 2013

Tags: listview, combobox

I have 2 Combobox (with ready items to choose from) and a textbox( that the user writes on).

I want the user to choose one item from each combobox and write something on textbox and then with a button to make all these 3 items to appear with their names in a listview.

The problem is that when I run it and press the button the items from the 2 combobox appear as a number depending on their position in the combobox (so if I choose the first item it will print 0, if i choose the second it will print 1, and so on... but what I actually want is the name of the item, not it's place in the list).

The code for the button click is:

```
    private void BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
    list.Add(new class(combobox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(),
            combobox2.SelectedIndex.ToString(), Double.Parse(textbox.Text)));
        ListView.Items.Add(combobox1.SelectedIndex + " " +
            combobox2.SelectedIndex + " " + Double.Parse(textbox.Text));
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the debugger to find the run time type of the object at `combobox1.SelectedItem`.

Assuming the type of the item is [`ComboBoxItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem.aspx), you can do:

```
String selectedValueAsText = ((ComboBoxItem)combobox1.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked! Sorry for the long wait but I was searching for my old questions and realised I haven't completed this.